# Not getting string response from responseText

Tags: javascript, php

I'm setting up a simple program for a website that updates a price for products as different products and quantities are selected from a drop down list. I am not getting back my string response into my responseText. Here is a sample of the code I am using in 3 different files
Here is the main page code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="templates/js/price.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="templates/js/ajax.js"> </script>
<?php

require_once(DATA.'dbOrders.php');
require_once(DATA.'dbCustomer.php');
require_once(DATA.'dbProducts.php');

$username = $_SESSION["loggedInUser"];
$email = getEmailByUsername($username);
$orders = getAllCustomerOrders($email);
if ($orders != null){
                $x = 1;?>
<table>

    <tr> 
      <td width="20px">Orders</td>
      <td width="85px">Date</td>
      <td width="10px">Qty</td>
      <td width="175px">Item</td>
      <td width="45px">Total</td>
      <td width="75px">Status</td>

    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($orders as $order){?>
    <tr> 
      <td width="20px"><?php print $x.".";?></td>
      <td width="85px"><?php print $order->getDate();?></td>
      <td width="10px"><?php print $order->getQty();?></td>
      <td width="175px"><?php print $order->getItem();?></td>
      <td width="45px">$<?php print $order->getTotal();?></td>
      <td width="75px"> - <?php print $order->getStatus(); $x++;}?></td>

    </tr>
</table><?php }


 $errors=array();
   if(!isset($_POST['qty'])){//Check if form has posted yet
        $_POST['qty'] = "100";$_FILES["file"]="";
        $errors['qty']="";$errors['img1']="";
        display_form();
        }

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //collect the information from the form 
            validate_input();
            if($errors['qty']==""
                    && $errors['img1']==""){
                place_order();}

             else{display_form();}
        }

        function validate_input(){ //check input for valid data
            global $errors;

            if($_POST['qty'] == "" || !(is_numeric($_POST['qty']))){
                $errors['qty']="<font color='red'>
                        ***Enter valid quantity***</font>";            
            }
            else{$errors['qty']="";}

            if($_FILES["file"]["name"]==""){
                $errors["img1"]="<font color='red'>
                        ***Please select an image***</font>";
            }
            else{$errors["img"]="";}
        } 

        function place_order(){
            if($_POST['back']== 0){
            $back = "1";}
            else{$back=2;}
            $item = "PC".$back."-46-".$_POST['qty'];
            $image1 = $_FILES['file']["name"];
            $image2 = $_FILES['file2']["name"];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file2"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $_FILES["file2"]["name"]);
            $username = $_SESSION["loggedInUser"];
            $email = getEmailByUsername($username);            
            $qty = $_POST['qty'];            
            $date = date("Y-m-d");        
            $customer= selectCustomerIDByUser($username);
            $total = getPrice($item);
            $status = "Processing";          
            $order = new Order($date,$customer,$email,$item,$qty,$total,$status,$image1,$image2);           
            addOrder($date,$customer,$email,$item,$qty,$total,$status,$image1,$image2);            
            $order->sendConfirmation(); ?>
            <h3>Order has been placed. Thank you.</h3>
<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='index.php';},2000);</script>
       <?php  }

function display_form(){

    global $errors;
     ?>

<div> 

        <form name="newOrderForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <table>
                <tr>&nbsp;</tr>
                <tr><td colspan="3"><h3>4x6 Postcards</h3></td></tr>
                <tr>&nbsp;</tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><font color="red">Front Side</td>
                    <td><font color="red">Back Side</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Full Printing</td>
                    <td><select name="back" id="back" onChange="OnSelectedIndexChange();">
                    <option value="2">Full Color</option>
                    <option value="0">No Printing</option>
                    <option value="1">Black or Gray scale</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quantity</td>
                    <td><select name="qty" id="qty" onChange="OnSelectedIndexChange();">
                    <option value="<?php echo $_POST['qty']; ?>"><?php echo $_POST['qty']; ?></option>      

                    <option value="500">500</option><option value="1000">1000</option>
                    <option value="2000">2000</option><option value="2500">2500</option>
                    <option value="3000">3000</option><option value="4000">4000</option>
                    <option value="5000">5000</option><option value="6000">6000</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><?php echo $errors['qty']; ?></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Price:<textarea id="price"></textarea></td>
                </tr>

                <tr><td>
                    <label for="file">Font image:</label>                
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/> </td> 
                    <td><?php echo $errors['img1']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>
                    <label for="file2">Back image:</label>                
                <input type="file" name="file2" id="file2"/> </td> 
                    <td><?php echo $errors['img2']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="1"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Order" /></td>                    
                    <td colspan="1"><input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form> 
        <?php } ?>
</div>
```

This code startes the process when the onChange event happens on the main page:
price.js:

```
    function OnSelectedIndexChange()
{
    var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
    var back = document.getElementById('back').value;

    var url = "includes/getPrice.php?qty=" + escape(qty) +
                             "&back=" + escape(back);                  

    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = displayPrice; 
    request.send(null);

}

function displayPrice() {

    if (request.readyState === 4) {
    if (request.status === 200) {

      var price = request.responseText;

      /* Update the HTML web form */
      document.getElementById("price").value = price;

    }    
  }  
}
```

This is my ajax code
ajax.js

```
    var request = null;
try {
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (trymicrosoft) {
  try {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (othermicrosoft) {
    try {
      request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (failed) {
      request = null;
    }
  }
}

if (request === null)
  alert("Error creating request object!");
```

And then this the php file
getPrice.php

```
<?php
require(DATA.'dbProducts.php');

$qty = $_REQUEST['qty'];
$back = $_REQUEST['back'];


echo "hi";

?>
```

When a change is made in one of the drop down lists "hi" should appear in the 'price' textbox (as it is coded now), but nothing shows up.

Comment: Would you mind showing us some backend code? Usually such errors are because of backend errors. Have you checked the value that will be returned i.e with a debugger?

Answer (score -1):

is request1 a global variable? is hard to follow it through the functions, have you shared all your js?

EDIT:

you can try following:

```
function loadPrice(url)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function OnSelectedIndexChange()
{
    loadPrice('includes/getPrice.php')
}
```

do you get any response now from your php file?

EDIT 2

Please check this tutorial and see if there's something missing in your ajax request http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_suggest

Comment: All my js code is there. I only took code out of the php file that showed the db access.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I did some code changes to the price.js file and the ajax.js file... see above for updated code

Comment: I updated my answer, please check if it works for you.

Comment: I changed the code and the alert still shows nothing. @Medda86

Comment: if you go to your php file through the browser, do you get the "hello" message? can be an error in your php file. You cna also change the url in the js to be absolute like with the full url using http

Comment: Yes, if I directly access the getPrice.php file, I do get the message display. @Medda86

Comment: if you use chrome, you can click ctrl+alt+i and then you cna click the console. Run your page and select an index and se if you get an eror message. Have you tried with absolute url with http to your getPrice.php?

Comment: I haven't tried a absolute path but I think it is accessing the file correctly because if the path isn't corrent, the xmlhttp.status returns a '404' for file not found. @Medda86

Comment: @user3434999 hmm I dont know what is wrong then. you got anything from the chrome console?

Comment: please check my edit and check the link for the tutorial, is weird if it doesnt work for you.